# how to insert multiple checkbox values into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created a contact form for the inquiry of customers, category and subcategory I was create using the checkboxes, it is the format of accordion
feature and subfeature are the checkboxes, I am using the insert query for the storing of the database, but I can't insert approximate feature with subfeatures.
three tables are here such as 'iv_mail',iv_mail_features','iv_mail_subfeatures`.
shown below the code

```
$data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('sendname'),
            'lastname'=>$this->input->post('sendlname'),
            'mobile'=>$this->input->post('sendphone'),
            'location'=>$this->input->post('sendlocation'));
$this->db->insert('iv_mail',$data);
$insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();
foreach($this->input->post('features') as $feature){
    $data=array('mail_id'=>$insert_id,
                'featurename'=> $feature);
    $this->db->insert('iv_mail_features',$data);
    $sub_id=$this->db->insert_id();
    foreach($this->input->post('sub_feature') as $subfeature){
        $data=array('feature_id'=>$sub_id,
                    'subfeaturename'=> $subfeature);
        $this->db->insert('iv_mail_subfeatures',$data);
    }
}
```

here i used insert_id, anyone can help me

Comment: Can you please explain in brief? right now what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

*You must do name all checkbox as an array like this.*

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="add"><hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="edit"><hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="update"><hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="delete">
```

*then in your function must be like this*

```
$inputnum = count($this->input->post('checkbox'));
for ($i=0;$i < $inputnum; $i++) {
     echo $this->input->post('checkbox')[$i].'<hr>';
}
```

*You can change the code as you want.*

*also, you can add all features as `json` in one column like this*

```
$inputnum = count($this->input->post('checkbox'));
for ($i=0;$i < $inputnum; $i++) {
    $checkbox[] = $this->input->post('checkbox')[$i].'<hr>';
}
json_encode($checkbox);
```